# Did Jerry Rubin eat so many carrots he turned orange?

Tags: nutrition

Did Jerry Rubin, the former Yippie leader eat so many carrots he turned orange? (I read that many years ago in an *East Bay Express* article.)

Comment: The condition is called [Carotenosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carotenosis). It's not extremely rare, it's harmless, and it can be treated by simply stop eating carrots.

Comment: related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39608/is-it-possible-for-a-person-to-eat-so-many-carrots-that-one-turns-orange

Comment: I think a broader 'Is it possible for someone to eat so many carrots that they turn orange?' would be a good contribution.

Comment: All it needs to make it a good skeptics question is a better notable claim ("This source did say it at this time" rather than "I think I remember this source sayign this onece years ago".)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Jerry Rubin](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/1981/10/18/jerry-rubin/beb88e6b-ba7e-4839-80ac-4442f6d47809/?utm_term=.128b98c85992), *Washington Post*, 18 October 1981:

> Rubin was taking so much carrot juice his legs turned orange

And the 15 February 1976 New York Times book review [Growing (Up) At Thirty‐seven](https://www.nytimes.com/1976/02/15/archives/growing-up-at-thirtyseven.html) says:

> He got into health food and drank so much carrot juice that his legs turned orange

So this story comes from Rubin's own 1976 book [Growing (Up) at 37](https://books.google.com/books?id=fyh0BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&dq=%22Jerry%20Rubin%22%20carrot%20juice%20legs%20orange&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-l7mk6KngAhVstlkKHY5QBNoQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Jerry%20Rubin%22%20carrot%20juice%20legs%20orange&f=false)